# Manipulating a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am still quite new to python so any help would be much appreciated.
I had two lists of tuples consisting of int, float and int, float float where the intergers are the same in both lists.
I have since merged these two lists into a list of lists using
        z = List1
        L = List2

```
z = [[r[col] for r in z] for col in range(len(z[0]))]
L = [[r[col] for r in L] for col in range(len(L[0]))]  

final_t_matrix = []
for i in (z + L):
    if i not in final_t_matrix:
        final_t_matrix.append(i)
Wind = [[r[col] for r in final_t_matrix] for col in range(len(final_t_matrix[0]))]
```

I now have a list of lists which if I run a print statement provides this (output this is only a partial output).

```
[1, -9.820569, -27.857089, 52.5], [2, -13.876759, -28.511313, 52.5], [3, -10.505768, -27.967606, 52.5], [4, -14.367771, -28.590508, 52.5], [5, -10.250126, -27.926373, 52.5]
```

I now want to manipulate this data by selecting the second and third value and taking the resultant and outputting this in a list.

my code is currently this but I seem to be missing something.  The statement needs to run until a none value is reached and then stop as the list can be over 500 data points long

```
force = [] 
i = 0
if Wind[i][3] == 30.0:
    force.append[i] = (((Wind[i][1])**2 + (Wind[i][2])**2)**0.5)
else:
    i += 1

print(force)
```

*I would like to keep the resultant in a list so that I can recall the resultant that corresponds to any integer.

Comment: I have tried running a for item in wind above the if statement but I get the 'int' object is not subscriptable error

Comment: if you mean this `force = [(((w[1])**2 + (w[2])**2)**0.5) for w in Wind]`

Comment: I need to be able to call the resultant values that correspond to the integer which is why I want to keep it in a list

Comment: Thanks mate tweaked that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

got a simple answer that when tweaked output what I wanted.

```
force = [(w[0], (((w[1])**2 + (w[2])**2)**0.5), w[3]) for w in Wind]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have square brackets enclosing your argument to force.append, i.e. force.append[i] in place of force.append(i).

I'm not sure if correcting this syntactic error will be enough, but it should be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the statements need to run until it reaches the end of the list OR the statements need to run until a None value is seen in the 4th element in the sublist?

If it's the first case, then you just need to put it in a loop:

```
force = [] 
for i in range(len(Wind)):
  if Wind[i][3] == 30.0:
     force.append(((Wind[i][1])**2 + (Wind[i][2])**2)**0.5)
print(force)
```

Otherwise, you need to put it in a loop and use a break statement:

```
force = [] 
for i in range(len(Wind)):
   if Wind[i][3] == None:
      break
   elif Wind[i][3] == 30.0:
      force.append(((Wind[i][1])**2 + (Wind[i][2])**2)**0.5)
print(force)
```

Note that this will output an empty list given the sample Wind list you've provided since there is no 4th element in the sublist that is equal to 30.